# Find distance, given angles of elevation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Write an equation giving the distance d between the plane and observation post in terms of $\theta$ and $\phi$.

[image]

Is this correct? when using the Law of Sines
answer:
$a/\sin\theta = c/\sin C$
$a=c(\sin\theta)/\sin C$

$a=d$

$\phi = 180 - B$

Any ideas if this is correct?

Comment: B is not an angle, it is a point

Comment: $\phi$ it's an angle. $B$ is a point, $180$ is a number. What do you mean by $\phi = 180 - B$?

Comment: Maybe he wants to denote $\angle{B}$ as the angle in the $B$ vertex...

Answer (score 2):

From [Law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) you should get:
$$\frac{d}{\sin\theta}=\frac{|AB|}{\sin(\phi-\theta)}$$
and
$$d=|AB|\cdot\frac{\sin(\phi-\theta)}{\sin\theta}.$$